# LLVM IR: How to get size of array, in llvm ir-code, when passed as argument to function?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I have a function that takes an array as argument and I need to get the size of the array first thing in the function. I need to do this in LLVM IR. Is this possible? I can access the array but I don't know the size.

```
void test(int[] a) {

}
```

is right now translating to

```
define void @test(i32* %__p__a) {
entry: 
       %a = alloca i32*, align 4
       store i32* %__p__a , i32** %a, align 4
       ret void
}
```

Comment: Which language is the first code block in? C? Or your own language that you're translating to LLVM IR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I need to get the size of the array first thing in the function. I need to do this in LLVM IR. Is this possible?

If all you have is an `i32*` with no additional information about what it points to, then no, it's not possible. In order to get an array's size, you'll need to store that information somewhere where the `test` function can access it.

Since this is your own language and you control what the generated LLVM IR looks like, you could for example represent arrays as structs that contain the array's size and a pointer to the data.